# wlan.scan() returning empty list & cant connect to network micropython

Tags: server, wifi, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I'm trying to create a sever with my raspberry pi pico w, but for some reason I'm not able to connect to the network. That is, after calling wlan.connect(), no matter how long I wait, it doesn't connect.

I've been following this tutorial to a T, so what they have here is exactly what my code looks like:
https://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/wireless-communication-between-two-raspberry-pi-pico-w-boards

Here is the code for convenience:

```
# Webserver to send RGB data
# Tony Goodhew 5 July 2022
import network
import socket
import time
from machine import Pin, ADC
from secret import ssid,password
import random
wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
wlan.active(True)
wlan.connect(ssid, password)
       
# Wait for connect or fail
max_wait = 10
while max_wait > 0:
    if wlan.status() < 0 or wlan.status() >= 3:
        break
    max_wait -= 1
    print('waiting for connection...')
    time.sleep(1)

# Handle connection error
if wlan.status() != 3:
    raise RuntimeError('network connection failed')
else:
    print('connected')
    status = wlan.ifconfig()
    print( 'ip = ' + status[0] )

# Open socket
addr = socket.getaddrinfo('0.0.0.0', 80)[0][-1]

s = socket.socket()
s.bind(addr)
s.listen(1)

print('listening on', addr)

# Listen for connections
while True:
    try:
        cl, addr = s.accept()
        print('client connected from', addr)
        request = cl.recv(1024)
        print(request)
        # Do not unpack request
        # We reply to any request the same way
        # Generate 3 values to send back
        r = random.randint(0,255)
        g = random.randint(0,255)
        b = random.randint(0,255)
        # Join to make a simple string with commas as separators
        rgb = str(r) + "," + str(g) + ","+str(b)
        
        response = rgb # This is what we send in reply

        cl.send(response)
        print("Sent:" + rgb)
        cl.close()

    except OSError as e:
        cl.close()
        print('connection closed')
```

Additionally, when I call wlan.scan() (which should return information about the available networks, if I understand it correctly), it returns an empty list. That leads me think that it probably isn't a problem with my ssid and password. I'm also trying this on two different raspberry pico W's, and it doesn't work for either of them.

Edit: connection works with a different wifi network. I think it might be because the one I was trying connect to will redirect to a web page to prompt for the password (for some reason). Would still appreciate any thoughts on how to get around this and/or why wlan.scan is not returning anything.

Answer (score 1):

The code only checks for one possible faulty condition.
there are more possible returns from `wlan.status()`

```
Return the current status of the wireless connection.

When called with no argument the return value describes the network link status. The possible statuses are defined as constants:

STAT_IDLE -- no connection and no activity,
STAT_CONNECTING -- connecting in progress,
STAT_WRONG_PASSWORD -- failed due to incorrect password,
STAT_NO_AP_FOUND -- failed because no access point replied,
STAT_CONNECT_FAIL -- failed due to other problems,
STAT_GOT_IP -- connection successful.
```

perhaps the more robust way is to check if there is a connection at all

```py
import network
import utime

# create station interface - Standard WiFi client
wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
# wlan.config(dhcp_hostname="foo-bar-baz")
wlan.active(True)
wlan.connect("IoT", "MicroPython")

# Note that this may take some time, so we need to wait
# Wait 5 sec or until connected
tmo = 50
while not wlan.isconnected():
    utime.sleep_ms(100)
    tmo -= 1
    if tmo == 0:
        break

# check if the station is connected to an AP
if wlan.isconnected():
    print("=== Station Connected to WiFi \n")
    config = wlan.ifconfig()
    print("IP:{0}, Network mask:{1}, Router:{2}, DNS: {3}".format(*config))
else:
    print("!!! Not able to connect to WiFi")
```

for a sample to scan for wifi networks see : https://github.com/Josverl/mpremote_config/blob/master/snippets/wifi_scan.py

the code should work on MicroPython 1.11 and newer including Pico-W